# How to read video in octave?

Tags: image-processing

I am working on a color transformation project using video.Can any one please tell me how to read video in octave.I have see aviread can be used to video frame by frame but i want to read the entire video file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [package from octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/video/index.html). I am using debian jessie and this version of octave-video producing errors and can not be installed. Also, there is no debian package with name octave-video.